# Wordpress: How to get plugin review information?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking for a code which fetches the plugin reviews posted by different users for a respective plugin, but didn't found any solutions which suits me best. Please help me out

Comment: Do you mean the comments for plugins posted at https://wordpress.org/plugins/ ?

Comment: I want the reviews posted for the respective plugin

Answer (score 1):

You should look at this documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress.org_API

I think this is the most far you can go: http://dd32.id.au/projects/wordpressorg-plugin-information-api-docs/

Comment: sure will look into it. Thank you for guiding me to a correct path